# Validation on md-chips with md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, requiredfieldvalidator

I am trying to build a page that uses angular material and uses elements such as `md-chips` and `md-autocomplete`.

I want to put a validation on this `md-chips` so that an error message will appear if there are no chips and a submit button is clicked, similar to the `md-input-container`.

For the `md-input-container` my code is as follows

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
      <label>Title</label>
      <input md-maxlength="100" maxlength="100" required type="text" name="bookTitle" ng-model="bookCtrl.book.name">

      <div ng-messages="bookForm.bookTitle.$error" role="alert">
        <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'maxlength']">
          Book title is required and it should not exceed 100 characters.
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
```

And an alert will appear if the validations are not met. How can I do something similar to the `md-chips` with `md-autocomplete` that has the following code

```
<md-chips name="bookAuthors" ng-model="bookCtrl.book.authors" md-autocomplete-snap
              md-separator-keys="bookCtrl.keys"
              md-transform-chip="bookCtrl.transformChip($chip)"
              md-require-match="bookCtrl.authorAutocompleteRequireMatch">
      <md-autocomplete
        md-selected-item="bookCtrl.selectedAuthor"
        md-search-text="bookCtrl.searchAuthor"
        md-items="author in bookCtrl.querySearch(bookCtrl.searchAuthor, bookCtrl.bookAuthors)"
        md-item-text="author.name"
        placeholder="Author">
        <span md-highlight-text="bookCtrl.searchAuthor">{{author.name}}</span>
      </md-autocomplete>

      <md-chip-template>
        <span>{{$chip.name}}</span>
      </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
```

What can be added to the `md-chips` in order to perform validation?

Comment: it need some customise , See more here , hope if this help , http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Veapvm

Comment: I've tried this just now, to put a custom validation, but it doesn't seem to work for what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Create div block outside of md-chips block and add red color. It will work similarly

```
<div ng-messages="{test:true}" ng-show="true">
    <div ng-message="test" style="color: rgb(221,44,0); font-size:12px">errroro123</div>
</div>
```